# Need multiple results from DB Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my scenario I have the following 2 tables:

Table 1: tdc_doc_field_def

```
Column 1: field_id
Column 2: field_name
```

Table 2: tdc_doc_field_data

```
Column 1: info_card_id
Column 2: field_id
Column 3: field_data
```

Inside of `Table 1` I have 3 field_names I need to get, `txtAppProposedChangeDesc`, `txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis` and `txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy`.

Inside of `Table 2` is the `field_data` for those fields.

What I need is a parameterized query that if I specify the `info_card_id` I am able to get the 3 fields of data. I have the following query that will get me the data from one field name data but not all three:

```
SELECT
    tdc_doc_field_data.field_data AS txtProposedChange
FROM  tdc_doc_field_def 
INNER JOIN tdc_doc_field_data 
    ON tdc_doc_field_def.field_id = tdc_doc_field_data.field_id
WHERE
    (tdc_doc_field_data.info_card_id = '[txtInfoCardNumber]') 
    AND (tdc_doc_field_def.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeDesc')
```

Need help to expand this to help me get all three, `txtAppProposedChangeDesc`, `txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis` and `txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy`?  I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT:

I need to return the result set into the mapped values into my SELECT AS query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you just need to use the `IN` clause in the `WHERE` statement

```
WHERE
(
tdc_doc_field_data.info_card_id = '[txtInfoCardNumber]') 
AND (tdc_doc_field_def.field_name in (
    'txtAppProposedChangeDesc',
    'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis',
    'txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy')
)
```

Comment: This is getting closer, but how do I map the field names back to my SELECT AS query?  I need 'txtAppProposedChangeDesc' to map  to 'txtProposedChange' and 'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis' to map to 'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis'.  If I do "SELECT *" it doesn't map the data.

Comment: @Mark - Do you mean that you need 3 columns returned with these specific names each one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys are defined as follows:

```
tdc_doc_field_def(field_id)
tdc_doc_field_def(field_name)
tdc_doc_field_data(info_card_id, field_id)
```

You should be able to find what you want with the following query:

```
select a.info_card_id
      ,max(case when b.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeDesc' 
                then a.field_data end) as txtAppProposedChangeDesc
      ,max(case when b.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis' 
                then a.field_data end) as txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis
      ,max(case when b.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy' 
                then a.field_data end) as txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy
  from tdc_doc_field_data a
  join tdc_doc_field_def  b using(field_id)
 where a.info_card_id = '[txtInfoCardNumber]'
   and b.field_name in(
           'txtAppProposedChangeDesc'
          ,'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis'
          ,'txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy'
       )
 group 
    by a.info_card_id;
```

Or alternatively, if you have a `info_card` table, something like this should also work:

```
select a.info_card_id
      ,b1.field_data as txtAppProposedChangeDesc
      ,c1.field_data as txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis
      ,d1.field_data as txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy
  from info_card a
  left join tdc_doc_field_data b1 on(a.info_card_id = b1.info_card_id)
  left join tdc_doc_field_def  b2 on(
       b2.field_id   = b1.field_id
   and b2.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeDesc'
  )    
  left join tdc_doc_field_data c1 on(a.info_card_id = c1.info_card_id)
  left join tdc_doc_field_def  c2 on(
       c2.field_id   = c1.field_id
   and c2.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeTechBasis'
  )
  left join tdc_doc_field_data d1 on(a.info_card_id = d1.info_card_id)
  left join tdc_doc_field_def  d2 on(
       d2.field_id   = d1.field_id
   and d2.field_name = 'txtAppProposedChangeWorkConductedBy'
  )
 where a.info_card_id = '[txtInfoCardNumber]';
```